# Google search API with C#

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, google-api-dotnet-client

I'm  trying to use a google search api using this code :

```
// perform search
WebQuery retreiver = new WebQuery(query);
retreiver.StartIndex.Value = 1;
retreiver.HostLangauge.Value = Languages.English;
IGoogleResultSet<GoogleWebResult> rawresults = GoogleService.Instance.Search<GoogleWebResult>(retreiver);
//declare results list
List<string> resultslist = new List<string>();
//add results to list
foreach (GoogleWebResult result in rawresults.Results)
{
    resultslist.Add(result.Content);
}
```

with this api - [Search AP](https://googledotnet.codeplex.com)

but i keep getting a object reference not set to an instance of an object error , could you please explain why and how its erroring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is missing some null checks, after looking at the [source code of GoogleService class](https://googledotnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#GoogleSearchDotNet/trunk/GoogleAPIs/GoogleService.cs). The method `Search<ResultType>(IGoogleQuery query)` return a null reference if an exception is thrown.

You can check the inner exception you might find out what is the exact error behind the null reference exception.

```
// perform search
WebQuery retreiver = new WebQuery(query);
retreiver.StartIndex.Value = 1;
retreiver.HostLangauge.Value = Languages.English;
IGoogleResultSet<GoogleWebResult> rawresults = GoogleService.Instance.Search<GoogleWebResult>(retreiver);
if(rawresults!=null)
{
    //declare results list
    List<string> resultslist = new List<string>();
    //add results to list
    foreach (GoogleWebResult result in rawresults.Results)
    {
        resultslist.Add(result.Content);
    }
}
```

As well, I suggest that you call the search method in a try/catch block.

Comment: Could you please share the Google API link for .net 4.0